# Avoiding spawn kills in team deathmatch?

Tags: battlefield-3

Pretty much a yes/no question.  Is there a way to keep from getting killed the instant you spawn in the game.  No so much the problem with rush or conquest, just the darn, pesky death match games.  Yes, the spawn points are supposed to be random, but it could just be the nature of the game, or trolls, that make the experience what it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, *technically* you can lay down a spawn beacon when playing as recon in team deathmatch, and thus "control" your spawn location by respawning on your own beacon. But this would be quite a bit of manual work every time you spawn, for a marginal benefit. Deaths and kills come very quickly in TDM so this would be .. tedious.

Beyond that you have no control over your spawn location in team deathmatch, and it is possible to spawn in a location where an enemy has the drop on you, or an enemy spawns very close to you and behind you. Note that this isn't *as* common as it used to be, DICE did patch away some of the madness; the game does *try* to spawn you in a location relatively free of enemies, but realize that in TDM things are very fluid and the enemy is constantly ebbing and flowing all over the (relatively tiny!) map, so anything can happen. In previous patches of Battlefield 3 the team deathmatch spawns were *really* screwed up and it was quite common to spawn directly in the field of vision of enemies.

Comment: TDM is a kill fest for everyone and everyone gets good and bad spawns so it kind of balances out.  If your gun play is on par then you can usually "fight your way out of the corner" and survive a little longer.  In fact, I've used TDM to practice and hopefully improve my appalling gun accuracy!

It's MUCH worse in COD games as the gun accuracy is much higher and there is no surpression effect that *might* give you a chance to fight/flight and survive.  Play TDM as it's intended and take the adrenaline rush.

Comment: this was profoundly broken in early versions of bf3 though, prior to them fixing it up in later patches. See http://www.pixelshine.net/howto/2011/11/12/battlefield-team-death-match-spawn-revamp/

Answer (score 6):

There is spawn protection in TDM, aim before you move and you should be protected 1-2 seconds

http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/forum/threadview/2832654624783579995/

> Increased the spawn protection time from 1sec to 2sec. The protection will still be immediately canceled as soon as the player moves or shoots.
>
> Spawn protection will no longer be canceled by the player looking around.

Answer (score 1):

Spawn killing, spawn camping, and spawn trapping are troll techniques as old as the multiplayer first person shooter.  Some games/game types will grant you temporary invulnerability or give you a "safe" spawn location where enemies can't go, but most of the "modern/realistic" shooters I've played don't have anything like this.

By and large I avoid the game modes where this sort of activity takes place, if I can.  That's about the only way to discourage the feeding frenzy.